# Переименование загруженых файлов

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте. 
Подскажите, кто, как реализует загрузку файлов на сервер. Имеется ввиду не сам процесс загрузки, а принцип хранения загруженных файлов.
Я написал свой скрипт загрузки файлов и сохраняю их в папку пользователя **с тем же именем файла**, что был на ПК пользователя.

Но заметил, что большинство сайтов после загрузки переименовывает имя файла на свое на пример тот же VK при загрузке фото **001.jpg** сохранит его под именем **QV00tYkq.jpg**

Кто в курсе, подскажите, для чего это делается и как создать короткое и уникальное имя для файла? Пока пришла в голову только мысль давать новые имена файлам по uniqid()

Comment: Снова столкнулся с проблемой получения короткого и уникального имени для файла.
Пока остановился на таком решении base_convert(uniqid(),16,36); // перевод результата работы функции uniqid() из 16-й в 36-ую систему исчисления.
Получаем уникальную строку длиной 10 символов. Пример 'egbtn3cktx'

Также использую свою функцию, которая переводит результат работы uniqid() в 62-ую систему. В результате получаем требуемую изначально длину имени 8 символов состоящую из цифр, больших и маленьких букв латинского алфавита. Пример 'FGkg11Em'

Answer (score 2):

> для чего это делается

Соображение безопасности, чтобы имена не могли пересекаться и чтобы никто не мог перебрать все твои фотки, получив прямую ссылку.

> как создать короткое и уникальное имя для файла

Один из способов завести таблицу с именами (имелось в виду имя после загрузки) загруженных файлов, где будет хранится ссылка на файл картинки (возможно несколько ссылок - большой, средний, маленький). Дальше полет фантазии, например: берем id загрузившего пользователя + время загрузки + id фотки + соль, загоняем их под хэш, и имя готово

Comment: По поводу перезаписи спорный момент, как  тогда быть в ситуации когда пользователь умышленно загружает изображение повтоно чтобы перезаписать предидущее? И как все таки получить _короткое_ уникальное имя длиной 7-10 символов а не 32 которые возвращает md5()

Comment: Есть алгоритм, который возвращает вроде 8 символов, точно не помню и его название в том числе. посмотрите может здесь что найдете для себя http://php.net/crypt

Answer (score 0):

лучше всего именем файла делать его хэш. например, так:

```
$name = md5(file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: после чего нельзя будет загрузить 2 файла с одинаковым названием ? :)

обычно делается: md5(insertedImageId . 'some static salt')

Comment: Если добавлять уникальную соль попробуйте, к примеру, время и дату загрузки, после чего уже шифровать в md5 или подобное. Шанс что в один момент времени будут загружать два файла с одинаковыми именами минимален.

Comment: А причем здесь название, @shurik? file_get_contents() возвращает содержимое файла, а не его имя. Но тем не менее, при таком подходе нельзя будет загрузить файлы с одинаковым содержимым, но разными именами